# Форма Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе в форму HTML(<input form и т.д.>) введенное значение сохранялось в переменной Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие срабатывает, когда поле теряет фокус и его значение изменено:

```
<input type="text" onchange="var a=this.value; alert('Value is ' + a);">
```

Событие срабатывает, когда нажата клавиша:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="var a=this.value; alert('Value is ' + a);" />
```